# Terraform can not create virtual network in Azure

Tags: ubuntu, networking, azure, terraform

Since couple days I can not create virtual network in any resource group.
I get the following message

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_network.qmlnetwork: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_network.qmlnetwork: Error waiting for completion of Virtual Network "qumulate_network" (Resource Group "QumulateCi"): Long running operation terminated with status 'Failed': Code="InternalServerError" Message="An error occurred."
```

I tried to change the names, ip ranges. Try to create a completly new resource group. Totally clean terraform workspace. Doesn't helped. Here is my code.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "qmlnetwork" {
name        = "${var.network_name}"
address_space   = ["10.4.0.0/24"]
location    = "${azurerm_resource_group.myproductterraform.location}"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myproductterraform.name}"
}

/* Add subnet */
resource "azurerm_subnet" "qmlsubnet" {
  name                 = "${var.myproduct_subnet}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.myproductterraform.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.qmlnetwork.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.4.0.0/24"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you answer, you are right. When you create a VNet, you need create a subnet in it.  Modify tf like below:

```
# create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = "tfvnet"
    address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    ##You need create a subnet in VNet.
    subnet {
        name = "subnet1"
        address_prefix = "10.0.3.0/24"

    }
}
```

You also could check this [example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-create-complete-vm) on official document.

Comment: Hi, I test in my lab, this works for me. If possible, I suggest you could test it :--).

Comment: Hello Shangbao. Thank you for your answer. The support told me its 48 hours to rollaut the patch which caused the separated subnet creation error.

Comment: Now its fine again. Everything working

Comment: @GergA Hi, but I more suggest when you create a VNet, you should contain a subnet.

Comment: @GergA You also check [official example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azure/r/virtual_network.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing outage in certain regions. As per our understanding Terraform tries to deploy a VNET with an empty subnet definition. This is a valid operation, as subnet definition is not mandatory (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks#VirtualNetworkPropertiesFormat )